# What is a ballpark figure for excuting the following Hive query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE; for a table with 8bn rows/40 columns/400Gb?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

What is a ballpark figure for executing the following Hive query: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE; for the following table:

- number of rows: ~8bn
- number of columns: 40, various sizes of int, doubles and strings
- size on HDFS: ~400Gb

I want to check any ballpark figures against the real figure to see if the system is configured correctly.

Apologies if I've missed something crucial, I'm very new to Hive and Hadoop.

Also, will the execution time scale linearly with the number of rows, provided the number of machines is scaled up as well?

Answer (score 2):

It would be impossible to provide a ballpark figure.

However we can list out the influencing factors:

- Number of Map Tasks configured in cluster
- Block Size (determines the number of mapper that will be used)

Execution time will again depend on these factors.

E.g. if i have 100 Mappers available and my block size is 128MB - I would need 3200 Mappers (400*1024/128). So assuming all mappers are assigned to your job it would take 32 executions of 100 mappers at a time (again assuming all mappers start and end at same time, which is a stupid assumption :)). So time taken would be 32*time per mapper.

I would have left this as a comment but i am not allowed to do so.